# Google reCAPTCHA 2.0 : weird too large white background

Tags: css, recaptcha

We've run into a weird problem with Google's reCAPTCHA.

You can see the problem [**here**](http://dziary.com/system/rejestracja), if you scroll down to the very bottom.

Everything was OK, but for some reason there is this weird white background underneath it.

Anyone knows how to fix this? I've tried all the "hacks" I could find.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your **CSS** file you've written as:

```
.textbox iframe, .textbox embed {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: 380px !important; /* and this height is causing the extra white background */
}
```

to override this you can do as:

```
.g-recaptcha iframe {
   height: 100% !important;
}
```

It will do the trick for you.

Comment: Forgot about that! Thank you.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay You are a genius, saved my day.